# Return page form

Tags: forms

I have this problem.

I send the email from `http://www.chocolate-shop.it/it/contatti`

but the page of return is `/contacts/index/post`

i can to modify the response page?

where is this page `/contacts/index/post`

how modify it?

Answer (score 1):

In order to fulfill,your requirement,***need to modify code of controller class***  `Mage_Contacts_IndexController` on function `postAction()`

which written at `app/code/core/Mage/Contacts/controllers/IndexController.php`.

So ***require to override this controller class***. You need change all
to

### Override controller code is look like:

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', "Mage_Contacts").DS."IndexController.php";
class [ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]_IndexController extends Mage_Contacts_IndexController
{
    public function newAction()
    {
        $Cmsurl=Mage::getUrl('').'contatti';

        //Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);


        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if ( $post ) {
            $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
            /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
            $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
            try {
                $postObject = new Varien_Object();
                $postObject->setData($post);

                $error = false;

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if (Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
                    $error = true;
                }

                if ($error) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
                $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
                /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
                $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
                    ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
                    ->sendTransactional(
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
                        null,
                        array('data' => $postObject)
                    );

                if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
                    throw new Exception();
                }

                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
               // $this->_redirect('*/*/');
               Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($Cmsurl);

                return;
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);

                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
               Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($Cmsurl);
                return;
            }

        } else {
               Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($Cmsurl);
        }
    }

}
```

### and config.xml code :

> ```
> ....
> <frontend>
>         <routers>
>             <contacts>
>                 <args>
>                     <modules>
>                         <customcontacts before="Mage_Contacts">[ModuleNameSpace]_[ModuleName]</customcontacts>
>                     </modules>
>                 </args>
>             </contacts>
>         </routers>
>     </frontend>
> ...
> ```

For How to ***override a controller in Magento checkout*** [this link](http://www.amitbera.com/how-to-override-a-controller-in-magento/)

Comment: I can not to modify only the page /contacts/index/post?

Comment: yes..you can do  then it does not  follow magento standard

Comment: if I would only remove the side menu into this page?